# Azure DevOps pipeline: publishing to the symbol server using DotNetCoreCLI

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, debug-symbols, asp.net-core-cli

We have converted our pipelines to use `DotNetCoreCLI@2` tasks. I do not see a DotNetCoreCLI task to publish symbols for debugging. Is there an alternative task to `PublishSymbols@2`? The PublishSymbols task is limited to the Windows operating system.

Comment: You can't use `PublishSymbols@2` as described in ["Publish symbols for debugging"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/symbols?view=azure-devops)?

Comment: I was wondering if there was an alternative that is not dependent on using the Windows OS.

Comment: How is `PublishSymbols@2` dependent on Windows? Are you trying to use a file share and don't have Samba?

Comment: My task failed when I tried to run the pipeline in Linux.

Comment: Did you get an error message that "The current operating system is not capable of running this task. ..." or a different error?

Comment: I think it was 'The current operating system is not capable'. I just tried it on ubuntu-latest and the task worked. I probably picked a bad operating system when I looked into this last.